# Android: Cannot resolve Symbol

Tags: android

I am currently trying implement a chat feature for my android app using the QuickBlox chat API. However, I'm having issues trying to import the sdk. I created a libs folder in my module hierarchy and placed the quickblox-android-1.1.0.jar file there and added it as a library without any issues and Gradle already put it as a dependency.

Here's where I'm having issues. Whenever I try to call an Object's function, it will throw an error saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'nameOfFucntion' " even though I have the import statement for which the object belongs to.

I have searched high and low for a solution without any success and I've been stuck on this for a few hours now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it?

Comment: I have tried this multiple times with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to my app level gradle file, and got rid of a lot of the red errors...still working on it though:

```
compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.6.1")
```